# why after looping there's a newline

Tags: c, newline, counter, scanf

so i'm trying to make a penalty kick scorekeeper.
i set it to be 5 rounds at first, and when the scores are tied, it will repeat another 5 rounds. the problem is there's seem to be a newline appeared after it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int penalty2=0,penalty1=0,i=0;
    char home[15]="HOME",away[15]="AWAY";

    printf("\nSTARTS PENALTY SHOOTOUT\n\n\t\t%s\t\t VS\t\t %s\n\n",home,away);
    do{
        char penal1=' ',penal2=' ',penal3=' ',penal4=' ',penal5=' ',penal6=' ',penal7=' ',penal8=' ',penal9=' ',penal10=' ';
        for(i=1;i<=10;++i)
        {
            printf("\nEnter X for MISS and O for GOAL\n\n:>>");
            if(i==1)
            {
                scanf("%c",&penal1);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal1=='O'||penal1=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty1;
                }
            }
            else if(i==2)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal6);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal6=='O'||penal6=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty2;
                }
            }
            else if(i==3)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal2);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal2=='O'||penal2=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty1;
                }
            }
            else if(i==4)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal7);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal7=='O'||penal7=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty2;
                }
            }
            else if(i==5)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal3);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal3=='O'||penal3=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty1;
                }
            }
            else if(i==6)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal8);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal8=='O'||penal8=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty2;
                }
            }
            else if(i==7)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal4);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal4=='O'||penal4=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty1;
                }
            }
            else if(i==8)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal9);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal9=='O'||penal9=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty2;
                }
            }
            else if(i==9)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal5);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal5=='O'||penal5=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty1;
                }
            }
            else if(i==10)
            {
                scanf(" %c",&penal10);
                printf("\n\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n-------------------------------------\n%-15s\t\t %c %c %c %c %c \n\n",home,penal1,penal2,penal3,penal4,penal5,away,penal6,penal7,penal8,penal9,penal10);
                if (penal10=='O'||penal10=='o')
                {
                    ++penalty2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while (penalty1 == penalty2);

    printf("END OF PENALTY KICK\n\n\t\t%s\t\t VS\t\t %s\n\n\t\t %d\t\t\t\t  %d",home,away,penalty1,penalty2);



    return 0;
}
```

sample screenshot : http://s18.postimg.org/eobqwmd6h/masalah_programming.png

(i can't directly upload here, still not enough reputation)

Comment: Use functions and loops rather than repeating the same code over and over again. And print your lines one at a time. You'll understand better what's going on.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&penal1);` --> `scanf(" %c",&penal1);`, add space

Comment: why don't you do this `char  penal[10]; memset(penal, ' ', sizeof(penal));`  and then use the array? also, your code repeats itself over and over, you should avoid that.

Comment: @iharob Had to chuckle with "your code repeats itself over and over" which could have been "your code repeats".  :-)

Comment: AS a suggestion, please use `switch` statement. Much easy to read and maintain.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions. i'm still learning c programming at my college & we still did not learn much yet such as functions topic & arrays. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the 2nd time through the loop, `scanf("%c",&penal1);` is scanning in the `'\n'` from the previous user input.  Add a preceding space like code used in other places to consume all preceding white-space.

```
scanf(" %c",&penal1);  // added space.
```

---

Code should check not only for `'O'` and `'o'`, but `'X'` and `'x'` to be certain some other input did not occur.

Comment: thanks. it really solve the prob. yeah it is still an incomplete coding. :)

Comment: The point of checking for `'X'` and `'x'`, is that had your code checked that but still had the `scanf("%c",&penal1);` without the space, your code would have complained that neither X nor O was entered.  Often input error checking is not only to test user input, but to also test the correctness on the coder.  Good luck.